# Questions about data storage / MYSQL

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection, bbcode

**1. filters**
I use PDO and wanted to know if it is still necessary potential escape characters like ('or'' =')
Already read a lot and some say that PDO is sufficient to prevent SQL Injection

**2. BBCode**
In a text field `htmlspecialchars` is the best option for not displaying html formatting?

Thanks

Comment: If you have 2 questions, ask 2 questions.

Comment: You will find most or all of what you need to learn on the subject, in reading these 2 articles https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724 Do take the time to read them both very carefully.

Comment: @Dude your answer was very helpful - you're good at it, thank you

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii I read now

Comment: @PapaCharlie What answer?

Comment: @PapaCharlie You're welcome. It took some time for me to read them both completely, but well worth it.

Comment: @Dude, are two questions related to the same topic, just not to be separated. Your answer is not added information ...

Comment: @Fred-ii, is much information for me, I will need time to abrorve them completely :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie My comment?

Comment: @Dude no problem... life goes on

Comment: @PapaCharlie I can't place enough emphasis in saying to "take the time" to read and understand them fully. You "will" thank me later for it. It took (me) the better part of 3 "months" to get to where I am now, most of it from learning tutorials on PDO/MySQLi and prepared statements, and here on SO after seeing questions/answers. Make yourself a nice big cup of coffee, have a seat, relax and read. ;-) Cheers

Comment: @Fred-II, I forgot to say that I'm reading ... I will not stop reading, it was just a manner of speaking - thanks :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie Good. The owasp.org site is filled with information and you will be spending a lot of time on it. If you're a speedreader, good. Just make sure you don't skip anything ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii-, I'm still reading the issue of STACK ... the question that u indicated, @ Theo says that the PDO is responsible for not inject sql - get it right? Already tried manually inject SQL tests using PDO and none worked, it seems that the PDO successfully prevents

Comment: @PapaCharlie Yes PDO is secure, however... don't let your guard down. Never underestimate a hacker and never trust user input; ***never.***

Comment: @Fred -ii, can improve security and set the input type using PDO, correct?

Comment: @PapaCharlie That's correct.

Comment: @Fred -ii, Thank you friend, was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PDO alone is not sufficient. Prepared statements, or escaping are the proper methods, which ever access methods you use. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. BBCode is not HTML. If you're using BBCode you don't need `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 0):

> if it is *still* necessary potential escape characters like ('or'' =')

As a matter of fact, it was **never** any use for escaping "dangerous" characters like `'or'` or `=`.

> PDO is sufficient to prevent SQL Injection

PDO doesn't do any protection just by itself. it's **prepared statement** that uses a **placeholder** for the every dynamical data in the query that does it safe.

For the cases not covered by prepared statements offered by PDO, either use [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) or format and whitelist your query parts manually.